# Does linux kernel optimize the package transferring if socket is connected to its host's ip address?

Tags: linux, sockets, loopback

Case 1: A process set up a socket connection to its own host using IP address(either "127.0.0.1" or "10.xx.xx.xx" same as its own host).

Case 2: A process set up a socket connection to another host

What optimization does Linux kernel do for Case 1? IMO, for Case 1, there is no need to execute TCP/IP protocol code.

Comment: There is no need for the packets to go out on the netwrok, but the need for all the TCP semantics remains the same,

Answer (score 3):

There are no optimisations for such communications, the TCP/IP packets still must pass through the entire TCP stack. Connection handshake, tracking, and filtering must be applied to the traffic even if it is loopback. This is why in performance bound scenarios a local UNIX socket is used instead.